# Is there a VBA code to record data from a Subform to a table in MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access-2003, subform

I have a table called RetailQuality and a form frmIFMultipleEntry with a subform MultipleDataEnter in it. I wanted to know whether there is a vba code which can record the entry in the subform to the table when clicking add record.

Comment: Of course there is.  It would be more common simply to bind the form to the table, however.

Comment: @phoog Would you be able to help me out to bind the form to the table?

Comment: It's been years and I don't have Access on this computer, so I'm not even sure of the exact names of the properties (RecordSource? RowSource?).  The details depend on exactly how the relationship is defined between the data on the main form and the data on the subform.  You need to look at each form's properties (mainform and subform) as well as the fields on the subform control (the thing in the main form that contains the subform).